# iOS: how to add alpha to three layers of background

Tags: ios, interface-builder, layer, alpha

I want something like this:

[image]

There are three layers of view, first is the background.
Then there is an alpha layer,
and another alpha layer contains "SAVE LOAD"

My question is how to set the alpha value and background color for the top 2 views so that it can display this desired layering. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, it looks like

- 50% alpha on black
- 100% alpha on dark green

Yet, your designer might be a better fit to ask.

**Edit**:
You might have to play with the alpha on the black a little to get a good match without detailed information from your designer. As to the dark green, I cannot see any transparency, so I'd just go for opague to keep the alpha parts low for the graphics engine.

Comment: Thanks I will try your answer later.

Comment: Hi 50% alpha on black works great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to use the upvote button to say 'thank you' the SE way.